# Chart not displaying Aggregate SUM value in VisualForce using Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

I have an object Revenue__c that has 2 fields ... ProductType__c, QuantitySold__c. 
I want to showcase this below scenario as a bar graph :

**ProductType__c**    **QuantitySold__c**

```
  AC                      10
  Refrigerator            20
  TV                      30
  Geyser                  15
```

**My VisualForce code is this:**

```
<apex:page controller="AFS">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Quantity sold per product ">
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<td align="left">
<table width="10" align="left">
<tr><td align="right"><apex:chart height="240px" width="600" data="{!chartData}" animate="true">
<apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name">
<apex:chartLabel orientation="vertical"/> </apex:axis>
<apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" steps="1" fields="data1"/>

<apex:barSeries colorsProgressWithinSeries="false" tips="true" gutter="75" axis="left" orientation="vertical" xField="name" yField="data1" stacked="true">
<apex:chartTips valueField="name" height="50" width="120"/>
</apex:barSeries>

<apex:legend position="bottom"/>
</apex:chart>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 

<apex:form >
```

**My Apex code is this:**

```
public class AFS {
public class Data 
    {  
    public String name { get; set; }   
    public Integer data1 { get; set; }    
    public Data(String name, Integer data1)
     {    
       this.name = name;     
      this.data1 = data1;  
    } 
    }  

     public List<Data> getChartData()
     {      
       List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT Revenue__c.ProductType__c, SUM(Revenue__c.QuantitySold__c) sum from Revenue__c GROUP BY Revenue__c.ProductType__c];  
       List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();      

      for (AggregateResult ar : arList)
     {   
      String name = String.valueOf(ar.get('ProductType__c'));
      Integer data1 = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('sum')); 
      dataList.add(new Data(name, data1));
    }  

       return dataList;

       }

     }
```

When I run this, no graph is shown. The output only shows the below line:
Quantity sold per product

Let me know how to display this as a chart(Pie chart, Line chart, Bar graph). Any of these will work for me. Thanks in advance ... !!!

Comment: I don't see your VF code.

Comment: Somehow I am unable to add my VF code here ....

Comment: Added it finally .... @dphil .... I have tried a lot with these codes but still unable to find out a feasible solution.